# UIGestureRecognizer for existing touch

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

UIButton has a `touchDown` event handler. When it triggered the ViewController will add subview above the button. How to recognize a existing touch on this new subview?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

User this method, where "upperView" is the added subview

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([upperView isDescendantOfView:touch.view]) {
        // do work
    }
}
```

Also you can list the added gesturerecognisers as well

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.gestureRecognizers)
{
    //Do something with recognizer
}
```